# Python: combining less than (<) operator with `and` key word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading the docs of PIL, [Link](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html?highlight=mode#processing-individual-bands), and I found this line

```
mask = source[R].point(lambda i: i < 100 and 255)
```

So what does it mean that `i < 100 and 255`?

Comment: `i < 100 and 255` will resolve to `255` if `i` less than 100, otherwise it will resolve to `False`. It's equivalent to `255 if i < 100 else False`. Whether that is the intention or not, I don't know.

Comment: it means *return `False` if `i` is bigger than `100` or else return `255`*

Comment: There's an explanation in the doc  : "Python only evaluates the portion of a logical expression as is necessary to determine the outcome, and returns the last value examined as the result of the expression. So if the expression above is false (0), Python does not look at the second operand, and thus returns 0. Otherwise, it returns 255."

Comment: the fact that they are passing a `lambda` to a method is also quite unusual. They could just pass the `i` and do the calc inside the method.. Someone is too *funky* down @ Link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is featured in the paragraph right after:

> Python only evaluates the portion of a logical expression as is necessary to determine the outcome, and returns the last value examined as the result of the expression. So if the expression above is false (0), Python does not look at the second operand, and thus returns 0. Otherwise, it returns 255.

If `i < 100` is True, it returns `255`. This makes sense considering the whole RGB colour scheme where RGB(255, 0, 0) returns Red.

---

But yes, this is bad practise. It should be:

```
mask = source[R].point(lambda i: 255 if i < 100 else 0)
```

Much more readable...

Comment: Oh... sometimes I'm just close to the truth but I didn't know that... Thank you...

Comment: there's this `x or 12` construct which is much more comprehensible in the case of `or` and `and`. If `x` is `False` then it yields `12`. The `and` counterpart is IMHO cryptic as hell. So cryptic I posted a misleading comment in the first place ("this is a bug")

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Agreed, but even then that can be a bit hard to read manually unless we're dealing with single variables in the construct (i.e `x or y` not `(i < 100 and 255) or 0`

Comment: yeah, the idea is not to push it

Comment: To be fair, that code in those PIL docs is ancient, so it probably predates the existence of the `... if... else ...` conditional expression syntax.